# Split number into rounded numbers

Tags: python, rounding

Is there a library that can split a number into multiple parts, but makes sure all the parts are rounded numbers?

For example, splitting 100 into 3 would be `33.33`, but I would like it to be rounded and make sure the total sum stays as 100 also:

`[34 33 33]`

Comment: dividing 100 by 3 would not yield 33.3 in python. if you divide integers, your returnvalue is of type integer.

Comment: Well what I mean is that I would like something that allows me to split a number into multiple parts and make sure the total value of the parts is the same as the initial value, and the parts are rounded numbers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the builtin function [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) for this. Since all this function does is simple arithmetic, I'm using single letter variable names.

```
def parts(a, b):
    q, r = divmod(a, b)
    return [q + 1] * r + [q] * (b - r)
```

The return value is a list with the larger parts first.

```
>>> parts(100, 3)
[34, 33, 33]

>>> parts(100, 7)
[15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14]
```

Comment: great and quick answer

Comment: Would it also be possible that the first number would always be around 40% of the initial number, and the rest of the numbers get their share of the leftover?

Comment: This function will always return the list sorted. So you can simply reorder the output from the function.

Comment: I mean if I would like 6 numbers and the amount is 100 and the first have to be 40%, the output would be:

40 12 12 12 12 12

so first number always 40% and the rest shared

Comment: You just proved it's possible! Now you just write a python function to split the number in 40/60 parts, and then pass the 60% part to the function in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think this is what you wanted

```
number=100
div=3
#find the dividend of the number in this case 33

dividend=int(number/div)
#makea a list to store the numbers

listofrequirednumbers=[dividend]*div
#find the numbers remaining from 100 ie 100-33*3=1 one 
#one number should be added to the list 

for i in range(number%div):
    listofrequirednumbers[i]+=1

print(listofrequirednumbers)
```

Output

```
[34, 33, 33]
```

Comment: @p0nts Well if you find this useful make sure to mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your inputs are integers, another approach could be the following:

```
def divNum(num, parts):
    #Compute integer division
    p = num/parts

    #Check if there's a reminder
    if p*parts == num:
        #No reminder, return the integers as they are
        return [p]*parts
    else:
        #Compute how much is the reminder
        missing = num - p*parts                  
        return [p+1]*missing + [p]*(parts-missing)
```

Edit: as suggested there's no need to check if the remainder is zero or not, so my code could be simplified as:

```
def divNum(num, parts):
    p = num/parts
    missing = num - p*parts                  
    return [p+1]*missing + [p]*(parts-missing)
```

Comment: The `if` block is not necessary. The `else` part will give the correct return value even if `missing == 0`. For example `divNum(15, 3)` will give you `[] + [5,5,5] == [5,5,5]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement it without libraries.

1) If the number `n` is divided by 3, then the output would be `[n/3, n/3, n/3]`

2) If the number `n = 3k + 1(k>=0)`, then the output would be `[(n/3)+1, n/3, n/3]`

3) Otherwise, the output would be `[(n/3)+1, (n/3)+1, n/3]`